# Grouping data and assigning alphabet and numeric values for new categories

Tags: awk, perl

I have 4 columns in my tab delimited data, I need to perform 2 steps.

1. Group the data according to combinations of first 2 columns.
2. Every time a new combination of values appear in the concatenated values (col 4) for a particular group (col2), I need to assign a new category for that row both alphabetically and numerically. If that combination has been encountered earlier, then the corresponding category is assigned.

Input file looks like

```
Line    Group   Name    Value
L1  G1  AX27    A
L1  G1  AX25    T
L1  G1  AX356   G
L1  G2  1X87    C
L1  G2  AX78    A
L1  G2  AX987   A
L1  G2  AX001B  A
L1  G3  A2XTR1  A
L1  G3  A2XTR2  T
L2  G1  AX27    A
L2  G1  AX25    T
L2  G1  AX356   C
L2  G2  1X87    G
L2  G2  AX78    T
L2  G2  AX987   A
L2  G2  AX001B  A
L2  G3  A2XTR1  A
L2  G3  A2XTR2  T
L3  G1  AX25    T
L3  G1  AX356   G
L3  G2  AX987   A
L3  G2  AX001B  A
L3  G3  A2XTR1  A
L3  G3  A2XTR2  C
L4  G1  AX27    A
L4  G1  AX25    T
L4  G1  AX356   G
L4  G3  A2XTR1  A
L4  G3  A2XTR2  C
L5  G3  A2XTR1  A
L5  G3  A2XTR2  T
```

The intermediate output file looks like

```
Line    Group   Collapsednames  Collapsedvalues
L1  G1  AX27 AX25 AX356 A T G 
L2  G1  AX27 AX25 AX356 A T C
L3  G1  AX25 AX356  T G
L4  G1  AX27 AX25 AX356 A T G 
L1  G2  1X87 AX78 AX987 AX001B  C A A A
L2  G2  1X87 AX78 AX987 AX001B  G T A A 
L3  G2  AX987 AX001B    A A
L1  G3  A2XTR1 A2XTR2   A T
L2  G3  A2XTR1 A2XTR2   A T
L3  G3  A2XTR1 A2XTR2   A C
L4  G3  A2XTR1 A2XTR2   A C
L5  G3  A2XTR1 A2XTR2   A T
```

For all the lines (L1 through L4) , G1 has 3 distinct combinations  (A T G , A T C, TG ) where the combination (A T G) is duplicated.  So we can assign the alphabetic categories A,B nad C to each of these combinations where A appears twice.

So the final output will look like

```
Line    Group   Collapsednames  Collapsedvalues Alpha_Category  Number_Category
L1  G1  AX27 AX25 AX356 A T G   A   1
L2  G1  AX27 AX25 AX356 A T C   B   2
L3  G1  AX25 AX356  T G C   3
L4  G1  AX27 AX25 AX356 A T G   A   1
L1  G2  1X87 AX78 AX987 AX001B  C A A A A   1
L2  G2  1X87 AX78 AX987 AX001B  G T A A     B   2
L3  G2  AX987 AX001B    A A C   3
L1  G3  A2XTR1 A2XTR2   A T A   1
L2  G3  A2XTR1 A2XTR2   A T A   1
L3  G3  A2XTR1 A2XTR2   A C B   2
L4  G3  A2XTR1 A2XTR2   A C B   2
L5  G3  A2XTR1 A2XTR2   A T A   1
```

Here is what I have tried for step 1, but not working. I have little idea how to proceed to step 2 , once I figure out step 1.

```
awk -F"\t" '{if(a[$1$2]){a[$1$2]=a[$1$2]" "$3" "$4} else { a[$1$2]=$3"\t$4}} END {for (i in a) {print i"|"a[i]}}' file
```

Comment: To make 1st step `awk 'NR != 1{a[$1" "$2]=a[$1" "$2]" "$3;b[$1" "$2]=b[$1" "$2]" "$4}END{for (idx in a) print idx,a[idx],b[idx]}' | sort -k2,2` but I didn't clear understand what we need to do with 2nd step

Comment: With sorting `awk 'NR != 1{SUBSEP=" "; a[$1,$2]=a[$1,$2]" "$3;b[$1,$2]=b[$1,$2]" "$4}END{for (idx in a) print idx a[idx] b[idx]}'| sort -k2,2 -k1,1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as easy as it seems. Perl solution, I tried to be a bit more verbose to make the code understandable. Basic knowldedge of nested data structures (hashes of hashes, hashes of arrays) is needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my (%collapsed, %groups);

<>;  # Skip header.
while (<>) {
    my ($line, $group, $name, $value) = split;
    push @{ $collapsed{$line}{$group}{names}  }, $name;
    push @{ $collapsed{$line}{$group}{values} }, $value;
    undef $groups{$group};
}

for my $group (sort keys %groups) {
    for my $line (sort keys %collapsed) {
        next unless $collapsed{$line}{$group};
        my $value = join q(), @{ $collapsed{$line}{$group}{values} };
        $groups{$group}{$value} ||= keys %{ $groups{$group} };
    }
}

for my $group (sort keys %groups) {
    for my $line (sort keys %collapsed) {
        next unless $collapsed{$line}{$group};
        my $value = join q(), @{ $collapsed{$line}{$group}{values} };
        say join "\t", $line, $group,
            join(' ', @{ $collapsed{$line}{$group}{names}  }),
            join(' ', @{ $collapsed{$line}{$group}{values} }),
            chr $groups{$group}{$value} - 1 + ord 'A',
            $groups{$group}{$value},
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you,,this works perfect, i`m doing some testing , will get to you if issues come up

Answer (score 1):

`Awk` solutions (many assotiative arrays) but:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

BEGIN {
SUBSEP=" "
split("A1^B2^C3^D4^E5",c,"^")
}

NR != 1 {
L[$1]=1
G[$2]=1
a[$1,$2]=a[$1,$2]" "$3
b[$1,$2]=b[$1,$2]" "$4
}

END {
for (g in G)
  {
  i=1
  for (l in L)
    {
    idx=b[l,g]
    if(d[idx]=="")
      d[idx]=c[i++]
    }
  } 
for (k in a)
  print k a[k] b[k],d[b[k]]
}
```

And do the above script:

```
awk -f script.awk tab.data | sort -k2,2 -k1,1
```

If some explanation needed please ask in comments.

Comment: thank you ! my actual L and G names are generic and do not look like L1,G2 etc, can this be accommodated?

Comment: @HiaSen I have edit the script. I didn't do such before to avoid additional 2 arrays, but in your case it is reasonable to add ones.